# Calculate $\int _{\Gamma} \frac1{z^4 +16}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Where $\Gamma $ is $|z-i|=1/2$ positively orientated.

I have thought of every method to do this but still cant. It wont factor such that it would be in the form of Cauchy's integral formula. It doesn't have any singularities so you cant use the residue theorem. It is analytic everywhere...

With the Cauchy-Goursat, I don't really know how to use that but I don't think it is $0$ since the question is $4$ marks...

Comment: Possibly $\Gamma$ was supposed to be $|z-4i|$

Comment: it was on a past paper and I wrote it correctly... I have no idea how to do it. But even if it was what you say, wouldn't the problem be the same.

Comment: It really is 0 then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**:

The denominator has poles at $z=2e^{i\pi/4}$, $z=2e^{-i\pi/4}$, $z=2e^{i3\pi/4}$, $z=2e^{-i3\pi/4}$, none of which is contained within the contour defined by $|z-i|= \frac12$.  Now, use Cauchy's Integral Theorem.

Comment: So it is continuous and holomorphic in the region and by Cauchy goursat, it is $0$??

Comment: @snowman That is correct!  Well done.  All the roots are on the circle $|z|=2$.  And the circle $|z-i|=\frac12$ is contained inside that circle.

Comment: How did you, so easily know that those were the singularities? Did you solve $z^4=-16$?

Comment: @snowman Yes.  Solving $z^2+16$ gives  the roots.

Comment: Thanks. Also what exactly is a simple closed curve because that is what you need for goursat right? If it were $|z-i|<1/2$, would it still be classed as a simple closed curve? And would you still be able to use goursat?

Comment: I'm thinking that it would still be considered as a closed simple curve but you have to consider if every point in the region is holomorphic for $f$ rather than in this case where we had to check if only the values that are on the circle are holomorphic for $f$ right? I need some confirmation...

Comment: @snowman Actually, Cauchy's Integral Theorem requires that $f$ be analytic throughout the domain inside the contour,